# Count(*) работает не так

Tags: php, mysql

После того, как поставил в запрос `COUNT(*) as count`, началась выводиться только 1 запись, хотя `$data['count']` показывает, что их 3. Если же убрать `COUNT(*) as count`, то всё станет нормально, будут выводиться 3 записи, а не 1.

В чём может быть проблема?

```
$query = $db->query("
 SELECT COUNT(*) as count, support_questions.id ... 
 FROM `table` 
  INNER JOIN ...
");

while($data = $db->fetch($query)) {
 echo $data['id']
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если нет группировки (GROUP BY), то весь набор считается одной группой, и, соответственно, вы получите одну строку.
Вам стоит почитать о [группировке](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_getting_summarizing_values.html).

Comment: @msi, добавил GROUP BY support_questions.id и теперь выводится 3 записи, но $data['cont'] показывает 1 :(

Comment: @ModaL не 'cont', а 'count'. Вы получаете две или три группы (для каждой -- одна строка результата с уникальным support_questions.id) и количеством вопросов по этому id. А что Вы хотели бы видеть? Не совсем ясно, что же Вы хотите получить...

Comment: @Modal, могу только повторить. Почитайте и разберитесь с группировкой. Ссылки вам давали.

Answer (score 5):

Это не проблема, а нормальное поведение.
Ознакомьтесь с использованием агрегатных функций например здесь:
http://www.sql.ru/docs/sql/u_sql/ch6.shtml
Если в выборке использована агрегатная функция, то возвращается одна строка, если при этом использовано GROUP BY то возвращается несколько строк.

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, да вроде почитал и не совсем понял. добавил COUNT(support_questions.id) в запрос и GROUP BY support_questions.id, но теперь всё наоборот. Выводятся 3 записи, но $data['cont'] показывает 1

Comment: Почему Вы хотите поместить это в запрос? Может так лучше будет?  

     $count=0;
     while(...){
        ...
        $count++;
     }

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, так немного плохо, так как если я поставлю LIMIT 10, то count будет выдавать 10. А мне нужно получить все запись описанным методом.

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, вы хотите сделать выборку, ограниченную лимитом, и при этом посчитать количество записей вообще. В MySQL можно сделать так:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS support_questions.id
...
```

и после этого выполнить второй запрос:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

См. [детальное описание опции](http://valera.ws/2007.08.29~sql_calc_found_rows/).

Answer (score -3):

Если простыми словами, то добавление count(*) схлопывает (агрегирует) все строки результата в одну. Вместо них выдаётся количество исходных строк

Comment: А в чем отличие ответа от двух уже имеющихся?

Comment: В том, что сказано немного другими словами